# RHEL7 docker-compose will not work "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 404"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, rhel7

Looking to fix this issue. I'm running RHEL7 with docker-compose 2.9.0. I've boiled things down to these files:

```
[<user>]$ ls -la
-rw-rw-r--. 1 glaisne glaisne 166 Aug  4 14:22 docker-compose.cloud-build.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 glaisne glaisne  76 Aug  4 14:04 .env.azure
drwxrwxr-x. 2 glaisne glaisne  24 Aug  4 14:12 helloWorld

[<user>]$ ls ./helloWorld
Dockerfile

[<user>]$ cat ./docker-compose.cloud-build.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  hello-world:
    image: ${AZURE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}<servername>.hello-world:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
    build:
      context: ./helloWorld

[<user>]$ cat .env.azure
AZURE_DOCKER_REGISTRY=<server>.azurecr.io/
DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=dev

[<user>]$ cat ./helloWorld/Dockerfile
FROM alpine
CMD ["echo", "Hello World"]
```

If I run

```
sudo docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.cloud-build.yml --env-file=./.env.azure build
```

I get this error:

*[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
listing workers for Build: failed to list workers: Unavailable: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 404"*

I am no Linux or docker guru, but I've done about all I can to fix this with no luck. The Docker service is running on the system (Docker version info below). Any insight on what this could be would be helpful. I've rebooted, Docker service has been given enough time to run, I don't see any network/firewall issues that I can tell ( from 404 ). I've even looked at the source (I don't speak go), and can't fine any reference to 'dial', 'h2c', 'workers.'

TIA

Docker version info:

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-209.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Fri Jan  7 13:15:46 2022
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-209.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Fri Jan  7 13:15:46 2022
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this problem has not yet been completely solved, but for the moment this may help you, try to set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` env var to disable the use of the buildkit API.

Reference: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13889

Note: If you use the `sudo` command for execute `docker-compose` please use the `-E` flag for preserve the env variables.

Comment: Thanks Enrique, I didn't see that post. I tried it but it didn't work. Note: I don't have podman installed, but I don't think that matters.
```
[<user> testdocker]$ set | grep DOCKER_BUILDKIT
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
[<user> testdocker]$ sudo docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.cloud-build.yml build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
listing workers for Build: failed to list workers: Unavailable: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 404"
```

Comment: Please try to execute to this way `sudo -E docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.cloud-build.yml build` (with the -E flag, we can preserve the env variables).

I update the main post.

Comment: Thanks, but no change in behavior. I did try to edit /etc/docker/daemon.json with 
   { "features": { "buildkit": false } }   but only got  "unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: buildkit."